# Python: Reading file into dictionary/list

Tags: python, dictionary, file-handling

I'm pretty new to python and am currently faced with a problem whilst importing data from a file into a small game.

I have a file formatted like this:

```
Playername1
A;0,1;0,2;0,3
B;1,1;1,2;1,3
```

I am currently trying to find a way to import it into a dictionary with the Player Name as a key and a list of dictionaries containing the letter (in front of each line) as a key and the value being a list of tuples (the coordinates).

What I've tried (and failed at) so far:

Using the dict() function in connection with the readlines()function as well as the split(;) function to split the coordinates. But whenever I try to read line one with deadlines(1) it doesn't return the whole line.

Looking for a way to do this rather efficiently. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: We cannot determine what the problem with  your code is without seeing your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Use the `csv` module. Read first row and store in the master key

Then read the rest of the rows and build a list of dictionaries using list slicing. To create the list, apply `split` on each cell value to create the 2-element lists.

```
import csv

with open("input.csv") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")
    master_key = next(cr)[0]
    dict_list = [{row[0]:[x.split(",") for x in row[1:]]} for row in cr]

result = {master_key:dict_list}

>>> result
{'Playername1': [{'A': [['0', '1'], ['0', '2'], ['0', '3']]},
             {'B': [['1', '1'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '3']]}]}
```